# Logstash json filter for only one level

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I use the following filters configuration:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "client-log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    urldecode{
      field => "request"
    }
    mutate {
      gsub => [ "request", '/log/', '' ]
    }
    json {
      source => "request"
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine when request is only a one level json object. If it gets more then one level Logstash is getting parse error. Any advice?

request example:

```
{
   session_id: "123",
   message: { 
      id: 1221
      //....
   }
   //....
}
```

error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-09-07T15:53:34.712000+0100", :message=>"Error parsing json", :source=>"request", :raw=>"{\"session_id\":\"8d078da0-74f9-11e6-8d31-6925e76dde0e\",\"level\":\"Debug\",\"methodName\":\"fetchExternalData\",\"class\":\"fetchExternalData\",\"lineNumber\":78,\"message\":\"{\"0\":\"fetchExternalData doFetch assets \",\"1\":\"http://lab6services:8080/alerts\",\"2\":{\"method\":\"post\",\"headers\":{},\"body\":\"{\\\"results\\\":{\\\"types\\\":[\\\"alerts\\\"],\\\"format\\\":\\\"table\\\"},\\\"filter\\\":{\\\"title\\\":\\\"new alerts\\\",\\\"filterType\\\":\\\"PROPERTY\\\",\\\"operator\\\":\\\"range\\\",\\\"field\\\":\\\"createdAt\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"alert\\\",\\\"values\\\":[{\\\"value\\\":\\\"07/09/2016 15:49:44\\\"},{\\\"value\\\":\\\"07/09/2016 15:51:44\\\"}]},\\\"aggregate\\\":null}\"}}\",\"version\":\"1.2.0\",\"user\":\"user\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-09-07T12:51:44.953Z\"}", :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected character ('0' (code 48)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: [B@51b925ff; line: 1, column: 161]>, :level=>:warn}
```

log line:

```
127.8.4.1 - - [07/Sep/2016:15:54:07 +0100] "GET /log/%7B%22session_id%22:%228d078da0-74f9-11e6-8d31-6925e76dde0e%22,%22level%22:%22Debug%22,%22methodName%22:%22fetchExternalData%22,%22class%22:%22fetchExternalData%22,%22lineNumber%22:78,%22message%22:%22%7B%220%22:%22fetchExternalData%20doFetch%20assets%20%22,%221%22:%22http://lab6services:8080/alerts%22,%222%22:%7B%22method%22:%22post%22,%22headers%22:%7B%7D,%22body%22:%22%7B%5C%22results%5C%22:%7B%5C%22types%5C%22:%5B%5C%22alerts%5C%22%5D,%5C%22format%5C%22:%5C%22table%5C%22%7D,%5C%22filter%5C%22:%7B%5C%22title%5C%22:%5C%22new%20alerts%5C%22,%5C%22filterType%5C%22:%5C%22PROPERTY%5C%22,%5C%22operator%5C%22:%5C%22range%5C%22,%5C%22field%5C%22:%5C%22createdAt%5C%22,%5C%22type%5C%22:%5C%22alert%5C%22,%5C%22values%5C%22:%5B%7B%5C%22value%5C%22:%5C%2207/09/2016%2015:49:44%5C%22%7D,%7B%5C%22value%5C%22:%5C%2207/09/2016%2015:52:22%5C%22%7D%5D%7D,%5C%22aggregate%5C%22:null%7D%22%7D%7D%22,%22version%22:%221.2.0%22,%22user%22:%22user%22,%22timestamp%22:%222016-09-07T12:52:22.928Z%22%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost:3000/main.worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

**--- EDIT ---**

I want to parse only the first level of 'resquest'. How can I prevent the filter to parse any nested json elements?

Comment: Can you show the error you're getting? also a sample log line would help

Comment: I've added log line and the error

Comment: It looks like the second level (like `body`) is URL-encoded twice. See in `\"body\":\"{\\\"results\\\"` the escaped slashes are escaped a second time. That's probably the reason.

Comment: No, it's that you have a json field (message), which contains a json object, but not escaped, so its `"` are used by the json filter and you've got an invalid json object.

Comment: What causes problem is this part: `"message":"{"0":"fe..." ...}"` (cut for more clarity). The content of message is json, with the quote unescaped, so the parser will think that "{" is the value of message and crash because we have an invalid character (0 instead of ,)

Comment: I think the best solution would be to change how the logs are created. The only solution on the logstash side I can think of would be to extract the content of the json "message" field and remove it with mutate/gsub before parsing the json. (I tried to do it but I can't get my regex to work)